# Fix man pages after disk was full

Tags: debian, disk-space, manpages

during an `apt-get dist-upgrade` my */var* partition had no free disk space left, which led to dropping **man pages** during the installation of the packages.

Now that I have fixed this problem, is there any way to get the man pages back?

I guess I could go through the logs, note each package name and reinstall them, but I was hoping, that there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is from an answer in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/debian-install-missing-man-pages) site.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep '^ii ' | sed 's/  */\t/g' |cut -f 2,3 | sed 's/\t/=/' | xargs apt-get install --reinstall -y --ignore-missing
```

Basically, what it does is reinstalling all the packages being careful that it's the same version as the already installed packages.

I recommend you to read all the explanations carefully before using the command and to do a first test add  `--dry-run` to `apt-get`.

Comment: Thank you so far for the answer and the link! I would say, that's generally the correct command. One problem though - I keep running into the message that apt "couldn't configure [package-name],  probably a dependeny cycle."
I added grep -v [package-name] a few times, but there always come new packages with the same problem...
Any idea?

Comment: I decided to go the safe way and reinstall the whole system, but I will mark your answer as correct. Still not sure what caused all the dependency circles though or how to skip all of them ...